# Drawing a rectangle from canvas with a timer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to do a timer where an outline of a rectangle is drawn and is completed when the timer expires. Timer duration is 10 seconds. So I've managed to do it for a circle:

[image]

However, I cant seem to integrate it to a rectangle. As when I use `canvas.drawRect()` it just draws the rectangle without filling it up according to the timer.

Here is the custom painter class with the circle implemented:

```dart
class TimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  TimerPainter({
    this.animation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, progress, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
        color != old.color ||
        backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

Shape which I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I tried :

```dart
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    // double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    // canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, progress, false, paint);

    Path path = Path();
    var radius = Radius.circular(5.0);
    RRect rretc = RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
      size.width*1.2, 
      size.height/1.4, 
      0.0, 
      0.0, 
      topLeft: radius,
      topRight: radius,
      bottomLeft: radius, 
      bottomRight: radius
    );
    path.addRRect(rretc);

    for (PathMetric iterator in path.computeMetrics()){
      canvas.drawPath(iterator.extractPath(0.0, animation.value), paint);
    }
  }
```

All I saw was a dot:

[image]

> Update: The dot was because it was actually drawing out but it was too slow, hence I only saw a dot. Using `progress*100` instead of `animation.value` was fast enough to draw the shape. Now I just have to tweak the time to fit 10 seconds.

Comment: what is `"filling it up according to the timer."` ?

Comment: @pskink like say it starts at 0 sec so the outline is not drawn, at 5 sec, the outline is half drawn and at 10 sec the outline is fully drawn. So in the first pict, it's like at 6-7 seconds where it's 60-70% drawn. Once it reaches 10 sec the outline will be fully drawn and it will remain so unless I load the widget again.

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PathMetric/extractPath.html - `start` is always 0 and `end` goes with your `animation` from 0 to path length

Comment: of course you can use `start` different than 0 - it all depends where you want your rectangle to start from

Comment: @pskink I'm trying it out now, will let you know soon :)

Comment: @pskink I tried it but the rectangle is instantly drawn (post updated). Am I implementing what you suggested correctly ?

Comment: see what extractPath returns

Comment: @pskink oh wait, do you mean like this  `canvas.drawPath(iterator.extractPath(0.0, animation.value), paint);` ? I tried this and all I saw was a dot.

Comment: @pskink I checked and the documentation says `Given a start and stop distance, return the intervening segment(s)`. So I'm just supposed to draw these segments right ?

Comment: @pskink ok its working now, I used `canvas.drawPath(iterator.extractPath(0.0, progress*100), paint);` Now I just have to get the timing right, but its drawing out the rectangle shape I want. Thanks for the help !! Post your solution as an answer and I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: not progress*100 - use animation.value*pathLength

Comment: @pskink ok wow that did the trick : `canvas.drawPath(iterator.extractPath(0.0, animation.value*iterator.length), paint);`. Now it follows the animation controller duration which I set. Just one thing, now instead of starting from no shape and filling it up, it starts from the full rectangle and slowly erases the line (basically the opposite of what I wanted). Any idea on how to reverse this ?

Comment: `(1-animation.value)*iterator.length` - but why dont you use animation coming from 0 to 1?

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot man, its working perfectly now !

Comment: but why dont you use animation coming from 0 to 1? now your animation goes from 1 to 0

Comment: @pskink I'm still deciding as to what design I eventually want haha ... 0 - 1 would mean the line fades away while 1 - 0 mean its drawn right ?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that: simply do your animation coming from 0 in the first step to 1 in the last step - like the "normal" progress that comes from 0% to 100%

Comment: @pskink lol alright, thanks for your help man :)

Comment: sure, your welcome, and btw use a short `RRect` constructor: `RRect.fromLTRBR`

Comment: @pskink omg that saves me some typing, thanks !